# How to handle timeout for event based async service communication?

Tags: java, architecture, microservices

I got Service1, Service2 and these services communicating over Kafka. When I send a request from Service1 to Service2, I need to be sure within 10 seconds Service1 must get a response back from Service2. If it doesn't I need to update request status to "timeout" at Service1.

I need to send hundreds of request per second and I don't think starting scheduled task per request is an efficient way. Is there any other way to handle timeout case?

```
void sendRequestToKafka(){
    //Send request to Kafka

    Runnable checkRequestCompleted = () -> {
        //Check request has a response from database
        //If not update request status to timeout
    };

    ScheduledExecutorService executorService= Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
    executorService.schedule(checkRequestCompleted, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
```

Database schema;

```
id|request|response|status(started, timeout, completed)
```

[image]

Comment: Why don´t you run one job that periodically updates jobs that have run in a timeout? Also, if the requirement must be stricty met, you have to additionally validate for each incoming response if it has arrived within the required time frame (before processing in Service 1).

Comment: @Glains I already got a column like requestSendDate and checking incoming response if it has arrived within the required time. Periodically checking and updating requests can be more efficient.

Comment: Can you explain your previous statement? I did not get your point.

Comment: "Why don´t you run one job that periodically updates jobs that have run in a timeout?" I will.  "you have to additionally validate for each incoming response" I already got such a control.